# How do I make a node follow another node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my game, I have a bunch of circles moving up in a straight that my player is supposed to jump through repeatedly.[image: Example]

How can I  make my player (when resting on a line) follow the circles moving up? Will post code if necessary.

Comment: ive read this a couple times and cant follow whats supposed to be happening here

Comment: @hamobi the black circles are moving up and Id like the white circle to follow them when it contacts with the line